# Apache CXF and Maven java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

Tags: java, apache, maven, cxf, wsdl2java

I am trying to generate a few classes using Maven and Apache CXF. When i run maven clean install, I get the error as:

```
[DEBUG]   (f) wsdlRoot = C:\Workspace\SDC\ALLXSDSchemaFiles\src\main\resources\wsdl
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[INFO] Using proxy server configured in maven.
[DEBUG] Classpath: [file:/C:/Workspace/SDC/ALLXSDSchemaFiles/target/classes/, file:/C:/Workspace/SDC/ALLXSDSchemaFiles/target/classes/]
[DEBUG] Calling wsdl2java with args: [-d, C:\Workspace\SDC\ALLXSDSchemaFiles\src\main\java, -verbose, -impl, file:/C:/Workspace/SDC/ALLXSDSchemaFiles/src/main/resources/XSDFiles/SAPConfig.wsdl]
[DEBUG]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBUtils.unmarshall(Ljavax/xml/bind/JAXBContext;Lorg/w3c/dom/Element;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljavax/xml/bind/JAXBElement;
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.PluginLoader.getPlugin(PluginLoader.java:237)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.PluginLoader.getPlugin(PluginLoader.java:194)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:122)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.PluginLoader.loadPlugins(PluginLoader.java:102)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.PluginLoader.init(PluginLoader.java:79)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.PluginLoader.<init>(PluginLoader.java:73)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.PluginLoader.newInstance(PluginLoader.java:106)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.<init>(WSDLToJava.java:48)
        at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.wsdl2java.WSDL2JavaMojo.generate(WSDL2JavaMojo.java:414)
        at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.AbstractCodegenMoho.execute(AbstractCodegenMoho.java:279)
        at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.wsdl2java.WSDL2JavaMojo.execute(WSDL2JavaMojo.java:511)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.135 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-05-07T09:24:58-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/207M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.2.4:wsdl2java (generate-sources-1) on project ALLXSDSchemaFiles: org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBUtils.unmarshall(Ljavax/xml/bind/JAXBContext;Lorg/w3c/dom/Element;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljavax/xml/bind/JAXBElement; -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.2.4:wsdl2java (generate-sources-1) on project ALLXSDSchemaFiles: org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBUtils.unmarshall(Ljavax/xml/bind/JAXBContext;Lorg/w3c/dom/Element;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljavax/xml/bind/JAXBElement;
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBUtils.unmarshall(Ljavax/xml/bind/JAXBContext;Lorg/w3c/dom/Element;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljavax/xml/bind/JAXBElement;
        at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.wsdl2java.WSDL2JavaMojo.generate(WSDL2JavaMojo.java:434)
        at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.AbstractCodegenMoho.execute(AbstractCodegenMoho.java:279)
        at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.wsdl2java.WSDL2JavaMojo.execute(WSDL2JavaMojo.java:511)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBUtils.unmarshall(Ljavax/xml/bind/JAXBContext;Lorg/w3c/dom/Element;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljavax/xml/bind/JAXBElement;
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.PluginLoader.getPlugin(PluginLoader.java:237)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.PluginLoader.getPlugin(PluginLoader.java:194)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:122)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.PluginLoader.loadPlugins(PluginLoader.java:102)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.PluginLoader.init(PluginLoader.java:79)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.PluginLoader.<init>(PluginLoader.java:73)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.PluginLoader.newInstance(PluginLoader.java:106)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.<init>(WSDLToJava.java:48)
        at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.wsdl2java.WSDL2JavaMojo.generate(WSDL2JavaMojo.java:414)
        ... 24 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I used the same POM file and it worked about a month ago, but I decided to clean my repository folder yesterday and tried to run it again, and I get this now. My POM file looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ALLXSDSchemaFiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>ALLXSDSchemaFiles</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>

                <dependencies>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
                        <version>3.2.4</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
                        <version>3.2.4</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-core -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cxf-rt-core</artifactId>
                        <version>2.7.18</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-xjc -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cxf.xjc-utils/cxf-xjc-runtime -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.cxf.xjc-utils</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cxf-xjc-runtime</artifactId>
                        <version>3.2.1</version>
                    </dependency>                   
                    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.woodstox/stax2-api -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
                        <artifactId>stax2-api</artifactId>
                        <version>4.1</version>
                    </dependency>                   
                    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.woodstox/woodstox-core-asl -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
                        <artifactId>woodstox-core-asl</artifactId>
                        <version>4.4.1</version>
                    </dependency>



                </dependencies>

                <executions>

                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources-1</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <bindingDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/XSDFiles</bindingDirectory>
                            <bindingIncludes>
                                <include>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/XSDFiles/jaxb_binding_general.xml</include>
                            </bindingIncludes>
                            <sourceRoot>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/</sourceRoot>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/XSDFiles/SDCConfig.wsdl</wsdl>
                                    <extraargs>
                                        <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>-impl</extraarg>
                                    </extraargs>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources-2</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/</sourceRoot>
                            <bindingDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/XSDFiles</bindingDirectory>
                            <bindingIncludes>
                                <include>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/XSDFiles/jaxb_binding_nc3.xml</include>
                            </bindingIncludes>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/XSDFiles/msip.wsdl</wsdl>
                                    <extraargs>
                                        <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>-impl</extraarg>
                                    </extraargs>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>

                </executions>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I am thinking i got the binding files mixed up, but I am not sure though.

Comment: I was able to get it to work by changing the org.apache.cxf version to 2.7.14. But not quite sure, how to get it to work with 3.2.4.

Comment: Why are you mixing up different version? You can't use core from 2.7.x and run it together with the other stuff from 3.2.x.